# How do I forward a port 80 on my local pc connected to a droplet via OpenVPN

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server, port-forwarding, digital-ocean

My droplet has a public IP address,

I am able to connect to my droplet's LAN with Open VPN

My Local PC address : 10.8.0.2

My Droplet's local address as seen by me : 10.8.0.1

(I can access the whole droplet via VPN)

Comment: You can't forward a port on a local intranet to an internet IP address.  Other than trying to forward port what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I want my local pc to get a public ip address. I want my local apache server to run on port 8080 of my public IP

Comment: You are not going to be able to have people connect to your machine by using the public IP address of your VPS.

Comment: Not sure what droplet is, but I'm not seeing why one cannot "port forward" to a (open)vpn client if he/she can configure iptables on the server. The client probably need to use the tun gateway (i.e. the vpn server) as default gateway (i.e. `redirect-gateway` option), otherwise you'll need to do `SNAT`/`MASQUERADE` in addition to `DNAT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have already enabled IP forwarding (e.g. with `sysctl`) on your "droplet", then you just go ahead and configure "port forwarding" (i.e. Destination NAT) with `iptables`. Say the public IP is `123.123.123.123`:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d 123.123.123.123 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.2:80
```

The `-i eth0` part is sort of optional. It limits the `DNAT` to traffics from a certain Ethernet interface. You should either omit that or change `eth0` to the name of the Ethernet interface of your droplet.

If you want the `DNAT` to work on the server itself as well (for testing or whatever reason), you would need to add similar rule to the `OUTPUT` chain as well:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 123.123.123.123 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.2:80
```

Note that this obviously would apply only to the destination `123.123.123.123` (but not `127.0.0.1` or whatsoever).

If your local PC does not use the droplet as its default gateway when it is connected to the VPN (e.g. `redirect-gateway` is neither in the user conf / ovpn nor pushed by the server), then you will need to do Source NAT for the redirected traffics as well, otherwise the PC will reply "directly" (i.e. via its LAN gateway) and no reverse NAT would then be done by the droplet's iptables for the `DNAT`. The http clients will then have no idea that they are actually replies for the requests they made to `123.123.123.123:80`. Therefore, add the following rule additionally if that is the case:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -d 10.8.0.2 -p tcp --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source 10.8.0.1
```

Similarly, the `-o tun0` part is also sort of optional. So either omit it or change `tun0` to the name of the `tun` interface of the VPN server.

If the iptables of the droplet limits forwarding, with for example `DROP` as the policy of the `FORWARD` chain, you will need to add an exception for this. For example:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -d 10.8.0.2 -p tcp --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
```

Assuming you already have:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

By the way, obviously you would want to make sure that your local PC always get `10.8.0.2` (for example, with `ifconfig-push` in a CCD file for its CN, unless it's a one-to-one server configured with simply `secret`).

P.S. This answer assumes the droplet has the public IP directly configured on one of its network interface. If it is not the case (for example, some router is doing some NAT for it, for whatever reason), make sure you use the private IP configured on it (i.e. as seen in `ip a`) in the rules instead of the public one you use to access it. And in that case, it's not guaranteed to work anyway.

EDIT: Just noticed that you said you want to forward port `8080` of the server. Yet it's unknown that whether you want to forward to port `80` or `8080` of the PC, so `80` is assumed. (If it's also `8080`, just omit `:80` in `--to-destination` of the `PREROUTING` and `OUTPUT` rules and change `80` to `8080` in `--dport` of the `POSTROUTING` and `FORWARD` rules.)

Comment: Thanks ! I just did your first two codes. Works Like a Charm !. Thank you so much. Love You !

Answer (score 0):

As OpenVPN runs a network level (IP) based connection and you are after a transport (TCP) based forwarding, its better to handle the specific service.

You can run nginx as a reverse proxy on your public service and get it to use your local service specified as `proxy_pass http://10.8.0.2:8080`.